# Can both a grad. student & faculty member cosign a recommendation letter?

Tags: recommendation-letter

Can two people, a professor and a graduate student, sign a recommendation letter? The concern here is that the professor knows little about the student and the graduate student knows all about the student.

My concern here is that if the professor is contacted, he will not be able to provide further information, where as if I was listed as the primary contact: I could.

Comment: Incidentally, unless you have specific reason to think you will be contacted for follow-up, I don't think this is an enormous concern.

Comment: _My concern here is that if the professor is contacted, he will not be able to provide further information_ — Then he **can't** sign the letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like Noah, I had a situation where two advisors co-signed a letter of recommendation. I should mention that the people reviewing the letter found this an unusual situation—and had claimed that they had not seen that in twenty years of reading recommendation letters. So this is definitely not standard practice. I suspect it would be memorable, but I am not sure it would be actually useful.

However, the difference was that my two co-signers were equal in rank. Your situation has a professor with a graduate student providing most of the insights. I suspect you will need to have the professor adapt the graduate student's comments, and then sign the letter. In the case where feedback is needed, the professor would then need to get the relevant details from the graduate student.

Comment: Please see the slight change I made to the question, about being contacted post-recommendation letter.

Answer (score 6):

You can have more than one person sign a recommendation letter.  I had one letter signed by two people.  But it is unusual.  My understanding is that the usual approach in your situation would be for the graduate student to help write the letter, but only the professor to sign it.

Comment: (My situation was a teaching letter, and it was a somewhat odd situation where each writer outranked the other under different measures of rank.)

Comment: My concern here is that if the professor is contacted, he will not be able to provide further information, where as if I was listed as the primary contact. I could.

Comment: Um... Having anyone but the actual author of the letter sign the letter is _totally_ unethical in my opinion. If a professor can't formulate a recommendation on their own, they shouldn't "write" one.

Comment: @JeffE I understand your point, though sometimes you do just have to write letters for other people to sign or they won't happen.  That said, in this situation (which I have been in in the grad student role), I think it's better to say that the grad student can supply the professor with their assessment, and the professor can use that to fill in some details in their letter.  If they happen to do some cutting and pasting, that's between them and God.

Comment: @JeffE Broadening from the specific context of recommendation letters, it's ubiquitous for letters to be signed by someone whose subordinates had input into it.  The signer is taking responsibility for the content of the letter, not promising that no one else contributed.

Comment: @JeffE: This also ignores the reality of how things are done in other countries. In Germany, for instance, the head of the institute may have to sign lots of documents on behalf of underlings without full knowledge of the contents, because only the head's signature is "acceptable." (It's situations like this that also tend to leave "letters of reference" as statements of job duties, without critical analysis of the quality of the work.)

Comment: @BenWebster _I think it's better to say that the grad student can supply the professor with their assessment, and the professor can use that to fill in some details in their letter_ — I agree that is better, although better still would be "The graduate student (or other subordinate) provides relevant raw data, which the professor uses to formulate the actual recommendation letter."

Comment: @aeismail Yes, I'm familiar with official administrative letters from department heads, expressing the Official View of the Department, that are actually written by subordinates; I've written a few of those letters myself.  But even then, the department head is expected to have "full knowledge of its content"; that is, they **always** read and approve the letter before signing it.  Also, reference letters for graduate admissions (and for faculty hiring) are not official institutional pronouncements, but statements of _personal_ opinion; having anyone else write them is dishonest.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to imply, and I'm sure Ben didn't either, that it would be ethical for the professor not to even read the letter!  In my opinion that would be obviously unethical.

Comment: If a person's signature is on the letter, they obviously should be reading it. If they're not, they're putting themselves at liability. I would prefer to have both signatures, again for the exact reason that is being brought up. Even if only raw data is supplied, the 'Signer' cannot supply more than he/she wrote or has available. Whereas the Grad. student can.